# RecyclerView Initial animation not working when scroll to a specific position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I create a RecyclerView that has a started animation on it.
So, when the recyclerView is populated the first element "falls" from the top of the screens

RecyclerView

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Layout Animation

```
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/item_animation_fall_down"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    android:delay="15%" />
```

Animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="600">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-50%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="105%"
        android:fromYScale="105%"
        android:toXScale="100%"
        android:toYScale="100%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        />

</set>
```

Its works fine if the screen opens with the first element selected.
But sometimes I need to focus on a specific item in a different position of the recyclerView.

I Do that with this code:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(args.selectedIndex)
```

Is there a way to force the animation to happens on that scenario!?

Comment: what do you mean by "falls" from the top of the screens? :)

Comment: you can try `recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation()` after setting and passing data to adapter.

Comment: Do you want to play animation each time `scrollToPosition ()` is called? Or do you want to show a `RecyclerView` with an offset from the start?

Comment: Can you add screenshots of what you want and what is now?

Comment: try this: Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                        (position) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
                                : R.anim.down_from_top);    viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);

Answer (score 0):

`layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);`// Scroll to bottom

```
myRecyclerview. scrollToPosition(position);
```

if not works in some cases(Keyboard opening etc.), try using delay

Answer (score 0):

Since you're applying the animation to a view (list), I guess the best way could be to leave the list invisible, then make the list starting at the desired position (removing the initial objects or scrolling) and then perform the animation with `view.startAnimation(animation)` keeping in mind to add `android:fillAfter="true"` in the animation, so it remains at `Alpha = "1"` after the animation.